# docker deamon is not work in windows

Tags: windows, docker

I try to run docker in bash ubuntu on windows. But every time I get this message
"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?". If i run it in powershell - it work. Can somebody help?

Comment: Faced the same issue and just got it resolved. post my answer below hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the docker deamon requires some privilidges that you don't have when starting the bash terminal.

You can however use the docker command terminal which will allow you to interact with the docker deamon.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on this post: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/

Connect Docker on WSL to Docker on Windows
Running docker against an engine on a different machine is actually quite easy, as Docker can expose a TCP endpoint which the CLI can attach to.

This TCP endpoint is turned off by default; to activate it, right-click the Docker icon in your taskbar and choose Settings, and tick the box next to “Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS”.

With that done, all we need to do is instruct the CLI under Bash to connect to the engine running under Windows instead of to the non-existing engine running under Bash, like this:

> $ docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 images
>
> **REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE**

There are two ways to make this permanent – either add an alias for the above command, or better yet, export an environment variable which instructs Docker where to find the host engine:

> $ echo "export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'" >> ~/.bashrc
>
> $ source ~/.bashrc

Now, running docker commands from Bash works just like they’re supposed to.

> $ docker run hello-world
>
> **Hello from Docker!This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly**.